# BIOS cannot see Kali Linux boot option after external drive containing it is unplugged

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, kali-linux, dualboot

I successfully installed Kali Linux onto an external HDD and after the installation was complete I was able to boot back into it without pulling out the HDD. After that I went into Windows (which is the main OS in my PC) and unplugged the external drive and put it back in immediately to test if the whole idea works.

Unfortunately, though, after I did this and went into the BIOS Boot Menu, I couldn't see the Kali option that I could initially select right after the installation. I tried a few different things but the only thing that worked was reinstalling the entire Kali OS onto the external drive, which is a pain (and, of course, the issue persists).

Is there a way I can make the BIOS see the Kali boot from the external HDD again? Or if not, can I do this from Windows? I just want to be able to plug in the HDD whenever I like and go into Kali without too much work.

Comment: When you unplugged the drive, did you unmount it in Windows first by using safely remove hardware's eject function? The BIOS/UEFI firmware looks for a bootloader, so if it's not showing an option for the bootloader, AFAIK it could only be one of three things, either: (1) the PC has UEFI firmware and Kali wasn't configured for EFI boot during installation or the inverse and CSM mode is enabled, which it should never be; (2) not correctly unmounting the external HDD in Windows resulted in filesystem corruption from a dirty dismount; or (3) the bootloader wasn't configured on the external HDD

Comment: @JW0914 I didn't eject safely but I believe I configured Kali correctly. Also, CSM mode is disabled. As for number 3, can you be more specific about how I can configure Grub on the external drive?

Comment: @JW0914 I reinstalled everything and you were right about abruptly ejecting the external HDD. I safely ejected it this time and plugging it in seems to have worked. Thanks a lot! You may want to post an answer so we can close the question.